# NameError to load json file

Tags: python

I'd like to load data from json file

```
In [6]: import json
In [7]: position_links = json.loads(position_links.json)
```

It report error:

```
NameError: name 'position_links' is not defined
```

I tried alternatively with

```
position_links = []
position_links = json.loads(position_links.json)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'json'
```

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: what is `position_links`?

Comment: Add quotes around your file name. It should be a string.

Comment: `json.loads(position_links.json)` -> `json.loads("position_links.json")`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `loads` takes a string, but that string is a JSON text, not a filename. So that would just give you some kind of `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: @abarnert. I've never used JSON before, just assumed OP knew which function to call but not how :) Nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file named `position_links.json`, you have to (a) use the filename as a string, not a bare variable, and (b) `open` that file so you can read it:

```
with open('position_links.json') as file:
    position_links = json.load(file)
```

---

If you want to understand what's wrong with your code:

`position_links.json`, without quotes, is just asking for the `json` attribute of whatever value is in the variable `position_links`. But there *is* no value in that variable. You haven't created anything named `position_links` yet. Hence the `NameError`. If you want to use a string as a filename, that string has to be in quotes.

If you just create a value `[]` for `position_links`, it still won't work. Now `position_links.json` is asking for the `json` attribute of the value `[]`, and lists don't have a `json` attribute. Hence the `AttributeError`.

If just put it in quotes and pass it to `json.loads`, it still won't work. The `loads` function takes a JSON text, not a filename, and the string `'position_links.json'` is not a valid JSON text. So, all you'll do is change your problem from a `NameError` to a `JSONDecodeError`. To load a file, you need `load`, not `loads`.

If you just put it in quotes and pass it to `json.load`, it still won't work. The `load` function takes a file object, not a filename, and `'position_links.json'` is not a file object—it doesn't have methods like `readline`, `read`, etc. So, all you'll do is change your problem to an `AttributeError` looking for one of those methods.

If you put it in quotes and pass it to `open`, *then* you have a file object, and you can pass that file object to `load`, and now everything will work.